# Код на NotificationCompat не работает на android 2.3.7!

Tags: java, android

Код работает на андроид `4.2.2` но не работает на `2.3.7`
Вот код:

```
public static void StatusBarCompat(Context context, int index ,int img, String name, String podname, String perexod, Boolean nast){
        Intent notificationIntent;
        notificationIntent= new Intent(context, UChat.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, index, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(img)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        if(!perexod.equals(""))builder.setTicker(perexod);
        if(!podname.equals(""))builder.setContentText(podname);


        Notification notification = builder.build();


        if(nast)notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(index, notification);
    }
```

А вот лог ошибки:

> 08-09 17:31:46.460    1988-1988/ux.uchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ux.uchat.UChat
>               at ux.uchat.StatusBar.StatusBarCompat(StatusBar.java:17)
>               at ux.uchat.Post.Post(Post.java:34)
>               at ux.uchat.Servers.getServerUpdate(Servers.java:97)
>               at ux.uchat.Servers$1StartAct.onPostExecute(Servers.java:41)
>               at ux.uchat.Servers$1StartAct.onPostExecute(Servers.java:23)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Останавливается на строчке:

> at ux.uchat.StatusBar.StatusBarCompat(StatusBar.java:17)

```
notificationIntent= new Intent(context, UChat.class);
```

Я зада вопрос уже давно а ответа так и не получил!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил ваш код, он работает и на 2.3.7, Возможно у вас ошибка в месте вызова, или проблема с контекстом/вызываемым классом.

Comment: Работает??? Както странно очень, совершенно странно, он работает на андроиде 4, но не работает на 2, ошибка в месте вызова должна быть и в 4 андроиде, если ничего особенного не поменяли, и проверяли другой код, в каменнтариях, он работает без compat, слышал на андроиде 2 он тоже есть, но и он тоже ошибку дает

Comment: Процедуру копировал один в один, только строку notificationIntent= new Intent(context, UChat.class); менял на   notificationIntent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); в gradle прописано minSdkVersion 10        targetSdkVersion 22 и compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' проверял на Genymotion.

Comment: Хм, интересно но заработало! Новый класс без компата, и со строчкой         Intent intent = new Intent();
почему так не знаю, главное робит! потом разберусь почему нехочет принемать